# Running C program with textfile as a parameter doesn't work

Tags: c, gcc

I have a simple program "prog.c" in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Count: %d\n", argc);
    printf("Text: %s\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program and run with a .txt file as parameter, the program does not recognize this parameter at all.

I compile with: gcc prog.c
which creates an "a.exe" file.

Then I run the .exe program with .txt file as argument (tried all options below):

`a < text.txt`

`a.exe < text.txt`

The output is always

```
Count: 1
Text: (null)
```

I am running everything on Win10 and using MinGW for compilation.

Comment: Redirection makes the command-line shell redirect the file to the program standard input. You read it from `stdin` like any other input with `fgets` or `scanf` etc.

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour when ran with no command line arguments. Always check argc before accessing argv

Comment: To clarify the comment by @n.m., the undefined behavior is from passing a null pointer as argument for the `%s` format, not for going out of bounds. The `argv` array is always terminated with a null pointer, so `argv[argc]` will be `NULL`. Since even for program without arguments, the value of `argc` will be at least `1`, then `argv[1]` is a valid element of the `argv` array (but as mentioned, it's a null pointer so not much can be done with it).

Comment: `a.exe file.txt`, no redirect.

Answer (score 5):

You want to check that `argv[1]` is set before referencing it with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Count: %d\n", argc);
    if(argc > 1) {
        printf("Text: %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Then you would run it like this:

```
./your_program argument
Count: 2
Text: argument
```

When you use `< test.txt` the file test.txt is copied to standard input of the program.  You would use, for example, `read()` or `fread()` to read said input.